# Where is a good site for a question about Windows and VirtualBox?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where is the best Stack Exchange site to ask a question about Windows 2008 running in a [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) environment?

Here is my question:

> I am hosting Oracle VirtualBox 4.322 on Windows Server 2012. One of my
> virtual instances uses Windows Server 2008. I can't turn off the
> Taskbar Tooltips on the taskbar, so when I move my mouse anywhere near
> the taskbar, a stack of tooltips appear (one for each open instance,
> such as IE or Visual Studio) and block a good portion of the screen. "Use Areo Peek to preview the desktop" is grayed out.
>
> Every suggestion I have found online is similar, and would probably
> work in Windows Server 2008 on a normal machine. But none of these
> suggestions work, and I am fairly certain it is because I am running
> in a virtual environment.

UPDATE: I found a similar screenshot online, as I can't post from stand-alone machine:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good fit for [su]. Adding a screenshot would also help.

Comment: A screenshot would be most interesting!

Comment: You say SO site, do you not mean SE site?

Comment: There should be a Windows SE. SU is too generic.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow was the original (AFAIK), I used SO. Sorry.

Comment: Add a link to your question on SU.SE when you post... :)

Comment: Shouldn't site recommendations be made on meta.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That is a perfectly acceptable question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), our Q&A site for help with general computing problems, including Windows and virtualization software.

All of the following are [on topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) there:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Your question, as phrased, is good. It is specific, reasonably scoped, describes an actual problem you're experiencing, provides a sufficient amount of detail, and can be answered directly. As Frederic suggests, a screenshot might be helpful for people to visualize the problem, if you can obtain one from your virtual environment.